# Remove chapter from ToC

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents

```
\documentclass{mwrep}    
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{c1}
\chapter{c2}
\chapter*{c3}
\chapter*{c4}
\section*{s}
\chapter{c5}
\end{document}
```

I know `chapter*` removes a chapter from numbering. How can I remove it also from ToC?
I want to remove c4 but not c3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To remove from the ToC all the entries associated with `\chapter*` you need to redefine the `\chapter@toc` command implemented in `mwrep.cls`; the following example code includes the necessary redefinition:

```
\documentclass{mwrep} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\chapter@toc{%
  \ifHeadingNumbered\typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
        \ifHeadingNumbered
 \protect\numberline{\mw@seccntformat{\HeadingNumber}}%
        \fi
            \HeadingTOCText}\fi%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{c1}
\chapter{c2}
\chapter*{c3}
\end{document}
```

To remove from the ToC only a particular entry associated with `\chapter*` you could 1) use the `tocvsec2` package:

```
\documentclass{mwrep} 
\usepackage{tocvsec2}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{c1}
\chapter{c2}
\chapter*{c3}
\settocdepth{part}
\chapter*{c4}
\settocdepth{section}
\end{document}
```

or 2) Use `\addtocontents` to appropriately change the value of the `tocdepth` counter:

```
\documentclass{mwrep} 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{c1}
\chapter{c2}
\chapter*{c3}
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
\chapter*{c4}
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And this makes every `chapter*` excluded? This is not what I want. I corrected my question because it was misleading.

Comment: @Ichibann: Yes. I've updated my answer to provide a solution for the new requirement.

Comment: Your secont way does not work (in example as in my edited question). First works without problems.

Comment: @Ichibann: what exactly doesn't work? In your new edit what do you want to remove from the ToC?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Solution 2) makes the ToC disappear completely. Solution 1) works great.

Comment: @stanwise Can you please please provide some code illustrating your affirmation about Solution 1)?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina What do you mean by providing code? It worked in my MSc thesis, which I will not quote here, as it's too long. And you already provided syntetic code for solution 1, which works for me.

Comment: @stanwise my bad. I meant, solution 2) (the one you said didn't work for you). By providing code, I mean a minimal, but complete document allowing me to reproduce the problem mentioned; obviously, this minimal document doesn't have to include any "real" content; there are a number of ways of obtaining filler text (if required).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Well, with solution 2 it is quite similar. It didn't work on my thesis. It also doesn't work with syntetic example that you provided. At least on my LaTeX installation (MikTeX 2.9).

Comment: @stanwise that's what I don't understand; the code I posted works as expected, so if it's not working for you, then you probably have other settings in your document. Or do you mean that the *exact* code I posted is not working for you?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: My mistake. I thought your exact code didn't work, but forgot to compile twice. After second compilation your exact code works as intended. However in my thesis I still get empty ToC. So I think that there may be some package conflicts that prevent this from working with my thesis. What is interesting is that when I accidentaly left `\usepackage{tocvsec2}` from solution 1, solution 2 worked. Unfotunately I don't have time to check every single package or setting dependency right now, so I'll stick to solution 2.

Comment: If you want to fiddle with it here is my main.tex: http://pastebin.com/fJqQt8VN In included files there are simply `\chapter`s defined. In MyPublications there is `\chapter*` defined

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, This only redefines `\chapter*{}` -- `\section*{}`still appears in the TOC, which is weird.