# Numbering of an Introduction in the ToC

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering

Does anyone know how I can get the heading `Introduction` and `Conclusion` in my project and on my content page without them being numbered. E.g just have `Introduction` and not `1. Introduction`?

Comment: \chapter*{Introduction} (if using `book` or `report` class)

Comment: \section*{} if `article` class

Comment: I am using article class. Thanks both of you for your help!

Comment: I'll keep that in mind next time Papiro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
\chapter*{Name of the chapter}
```

if using `book` or `report` class, and

```
\section*{Name of the section}
```

if using the `article` class

Please take a look at these posts for further information:

[Removing page number from ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/removing-page-number-from-toc)

[Remove chapter from ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24275/remove-chapter-from-toc)

Also, please always perform a search in already answered questions before submitting one.