# How to remove unnumbered chapters from TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, indexing

I'm using a template my college provided to write my thesis in Latex, and i'm having a minor issue with autoref adding unwanted chapters to the TOC (index), the relevant bit are as such I believe

The code can be seen here:

[sty page](https://www.codepile.net/pile/jy5jEk2L)

[main page](https://www.codepile.net/pile/JyE6nKgG)

[chapter to be included in TOC](https://www.codepile.net/pile/BAYzQxrO)

[chapter not to be included in TOC](https://www.codepile.net/pile/PDr6MdDw)

I tried following [this link from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544844/excluding-a-chapter-from-toc), and [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24275/remove-chapter-from-toc), but I can't seem to figure out the problem, specially because it only started appearing after I used the package hyperref to include the labels in chapters. I know that by doing \chapter*{}, however that does not seem to work since I included hyperref

The index appears like this:

[image: index appear like this]

But I don't want the unnumbered entries to appear (I mean Resumo, abstract, Indice, Lista de Tabelas and Lista de Figuras)

Comment: Please don't post links to code. Instead, make a complete sample document that shows the problem and include it in your question. In this case the sample document should include *only* `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{hyperref}\begin{document}\tableofcontents\chapter{DummyChapter}\end{document}` and any packages you are using that specifically affect the chapter formatting.  The template itself (either a package or class) can be linked if needed.

Comment: But looking at the code, the custom style explicitly creates a command for chapters included in the contents, and the `\myPrefaceChapter` command uses that and  the various `\myTableofContents` commands also use a similar command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the `sty` file your school provided, I found the following lines:

```latex
\newcommand{\myTocXX}[2]
   {
   \chapter*{#1\@mkboth{Conteúdo}{CONTENTS}}
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
   \@starttoc{#2}
   }

\newcommand{\myTableOfContents}
   { \myTocXX{Índice}{toc} }
```

So I guess your college really wants the unnumbered chapters to be in the TOC since they especially put it in the  `.sty`. So I wouldn't recommend you to change it but anyway.

By redefining the `\myTocXX` macro, you can achieve what you want, you just have to put the following lines before `begin{document}`:

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\myTocXX}[2]
   {
   \chapter*{#1\@mkboth{Conteúdo}{CONTENTS}}
   \@starttoc{#2}
   }
\makeatother
```

And here's my output:

[image: My LaTeX output for the answer]

Comment: +1 you'll also need to change the `\noNumChapterInIndex` command for other unnumbered chapters.

Comment: @AlanMunn I don't get why is `\noNumChapterInIndex` defined since it's just called in `\myPrefaceChapter` definition which is never used elsewhere...